# Can I have two distinct workspaces with two different layers reference the same data store in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, ubuntu, image-pyramids

Using geoserver 2.7.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

I have a large image pyramid I'd like to use in two workspaces simultaneously. Do I have to create two separate "stacks" of folders, stores, and layers?

or can I create two data stores (one for each workspace) that reference the same folder?